# Equality with Bilinear Maps

Tags: group-theory

Let e be a bilinear pairing function and $g_1$ and $g_2$ be the generators of $G_1$ and $G_2$

Given $e(a,g_2^x), e(b,g_2^y), g_2^x,g_2^y$ is there a way to find out if $a = b$?

Comment: can anyone help me here?